# Webcompiler - How to compile scss imports to css files in another folder

Tags: css, visual-studio, sass, web-compiler

When compiling scss from one folder to another folder, imported paths do not compile correctly.  I assume I'm just doing something wrong.  I haven't found any instructions for doing this (assuming its possible).

I have a "Styles" folder that contains my app.scss.  I then compile it to wwwroot/css/app.css.

**Solution Structure**

[image]

**Import in app.scss**

[image]

**Import in compiled app.css**

[image]

**Import in compiled app.css as read by browser**

It should be under wwwroot/css/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css instead of...
[image]

**Compiler Config Defaults**

[image]

**Compiler Config**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebooted my machine and now the path is compiling appropriately.